# Why is my counter out value producing StX?

Tags: verilog, fpga, test-bench

I made a simple counter that goes to 32 and a testbench for it. I'm not sure why the value for the output (`co`) is still coming out as StX. I've been trying to debug this for many hours now and I'm not sure of the issue.

[image: Verilog code]

[image: Simulation]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`co` is X (unknown) because it is a continuous assignment to an expression dependent on `current`, which is X.  `current` is X because you declared it as a `reg`, and `reg` types default to X at time 0, and then you never assign it to a known value.

Your testbench always drives `rst` as 0.  This means line 8 is never executed.  Line 10 will be executed at every rising `clk` edge, but `current` will remain at X.  X+1 returns X.

You need to reset your design properly.  At time 0, you should assert the reset by setting `rst`=1.  After a delay, you should release the reset setting `rst`=0.

```
initial begin
    clk = 0;
    rst = 1; // Assert reset

    #20;
    rst = 0; // Release reset

    #10;
    en = 1;
    init = 1;
end
```

Answer (score 0):

The reset of you counter is active high. You never set it to 1. You need to set it to 1 for at least one clock cycle.